# Updating a list in a fragment after an async response

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains a list of items. I am trying to update the list based on an async api response. My conditional logic is working fine and my log messages are working fine. Once in a few times the list does get updated but it isn't consistent.

How do i ensure that the list gets updated properly.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_container,
            container, false);
    loadContent(v);

    return v;
}

/**
 * Load content for the activity .
*/
private void loadContent(View v) {
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    info = new ArrayList<DataDeals>();

    info.add(new DataDeals(R.drawable.daily_deal_pic1,
            getString(R.string.blue_mountains),
            getString(R.string.australian), "150", "100", "45"));

    APICaller.makeAPICall("country-deals",
            "Default Message", Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap(),
            new Target.TargetCallback<String>() {

                @Override
                public void call(final String content) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (content.equals("us")) {

                                Log.d("US is calling!----", content);
                                info.add(new DataDeals(R.drawable.daily_deal_pic1,
                                        getString(R.string.blue_mountains),
                                        getString(R.string.liberty), "150", "100", "45"));

                            } else if (content.equals("uk")) {

                                Log.d("UK is calling----", content);
                                info.add(new DataDeals(R.drawable.london_eye,
                                        getString(R.string.blue_mountains),
                                        getString(R.string.londoneye), "150", "100", "1000"));


                            } else if (content.equals("aus")) {

                                Log.d("Australia is calling--", content);
                                info.add(new DataDeals(R.drawable.london_eye,
                                        getString(R.string.blue_mountains),
                                        getString(R.string.australian), "100", "75", "145"));

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });


    adapter1 = new DealItemAdapter(getActivity(), info);
    list.setAdapter(adapter1);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            launchActivity(position, info);
        }
    });

private void launchActivity(final int position, List<DataDeals> info) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            BuyScreen.class)
            .putExtra("title", info.get(position).getTxt1()));
}
```

Comment: adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Ram, can you please refer my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846096/populate-listview-after-the-addition-of-database/30858419#30858419 anewer. I did same for local db, you can do same for async task.