# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed(Signalr)

Tags: android

Showing following exception in my android app. I am using a single list view and single adaptor. I am updating  list view by using 2 different callback functions(from signalr) , but at a time only one.

**Exception showing :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131361927, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.indus.TAP.PanelDisplay$LogAdaptor)]
08-04 11:42:34.624: E/AndroidRuntime(7133):
```

**Code:**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        LogAdaptor log = (LogAdaptor) lvLog.getAdapter();
        log.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lvLog.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lvLog.smoothScrollToPosition(lvLog.getCount());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Yes , I called inside "runOnUiThread"

Comment: @FarooqArshed this code will execute each second as the result of a signalr call back method.

Comment: You should post `lvLog` code. This looks like a timing issue, `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called before the `post` call that changes the data. To test this hypothesis, you can move `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `smoothScrollToPosition` and do a test

Comment: @rangarajb2005, can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846096/populate-listview-after-the-addition-of-database/30858419#30858419

Comment: @RC. this will hide some data, Because the scroll didn't show the recent items when we call dataset after post.

Answer (score 0):

There are two key points :

1. make sure to invoke notifyDataSetChanged method when model changed
2. if you change the model in a background thread, use a broadcast to notify data change

Comment: In every 1 second there will be a new data (change in data ) , Now I am using a handler to change the dataset , this Handler is getting as a result of a signalr call back. Is any issue while using  a Handler to change the List View dataset

Answer (score 0):

If your SignalR is a service, you can try like this

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    private startSignalR(...) {
      ...
      mHub.on("broadcastMessage",
                new SubscriptionHandler1<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final String msg) {
                        ...
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Update adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged here                                 
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                , String.class);
      ...
   }
```

UPDATE:
Try delay execution after notifyDataSetChanged, for example:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                    
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         ...
         ...                            
     }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Not using the signalr as a service , just create a custom hubconnection class and using that.

Comment: I have just updated my answer, you can try like this

Comment: In every 1 second there will be a new data (change in data - will get 5 to 10 lines of data ) , So when I try the postDelayed, I lost some data

Comment: Have you run it yet? You can reduce delay to 100ms or smaller

Comment: Yes ,I just tried with one second. Anyway  I will try with smaller time values.

Comment: Ok, if my answer is suited for your case, you can accept it.